# AS3 : Scaling Sprite with Matrix on slider change?

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, scaling

I have a sprite that holds a bitmap data.
I want to give the user the ability to resize the image with a slider.
I am using the code beneath, as you can see the problem is that the scaling is additive so very quickly the image is gone totally.

I understand that i have to scale it in non additive way, just can not figure out how?

I tried to pass :

```
var m:Matrix = userImageCopy.transform.matrix;
```

when userImageCopy holds the original image. that helped for the scaling but then, each time the scaling started the userImage jumped to the position of the userImageCopy.

Any help?

```
function onSliderChange(evt:Event):void
    {
        trace( evt.target.value);
        //this will create a point object at the center of the display object

        var ptRotationPoint:Point = new Point(userImage.x + userImage.width / 2,userImage.y + userImage.height / 2);
        //call the function and pass in the object to be rotated, the amount to scale X and Y (sx, sy), and the point object we created
        scaleFromCenter(userImage, evt.target.value, evt.target.value, ptRotationPoint);
    }

    private function scaleFromCenter(ob:*, sx:Number, sy:Number, ptScalePoint:Point)
    {
        var m:Matrix = userImage.transform.matrix;
        m.tx -=  ptScalePoint.x;
        m.ty -=  ptScalePoint.y;
        m.scale(sx, sy);
        m.tx += ptScalePoint.x;
        m.ty += ptScalePoint.y;
        ob.transform.matrix = m;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than combining your center values with the current tx and ty, just set them directly with the `Matrix.translate` method:

```
private function scaleFromCenter(ob:*, sx:Number, sy:Number, ptScalePoint:Point)
{
    var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
    m.translate(-ptScalePoint.x,-ptScalePoint.y);
    m.scale(sx, sy);
    m.translate(ptScalePoint.x,ptScalePoint.y);
    ob.transform.matrix = m;
}
```